# How to create fixed menu in elementor but using fulljsplugin?

Tags: wordpress, fullpage.js

I'm using fullPagejs plugin for elementor and trying to create fixed menu like on this page https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ . I created new menu inside theme builder, but As you can see, a part of the page got torn off: https://sobotgmbh.de/pocetna-2/

Comment: If you purchased it, then you'll have [premium support](https://alvarotrigo.com/contact/). Just make sure to use the email used for the purchase when [contacting us](https://alvarotrigo.com/contact/).